# Verify Serialization/Precedence Graph

Tags: database, concurrency, transactions

I have a schedule here and the goal is to find whether it is serializable or not. I understand that for a schedule to be serializable, it needs to have an acyclic serialization graph/precedence graph.

```
T1     T2     T3
R1(A)       
              R3(A)
W1(A)       
              R3(B)
       R2(B)    
       W2(B)    
R1(B)       
W1(B)
```

Here is my precedence graph,

[image]

From the graph, it appears as though there is a cycle but I would like to verify this.

Is the graph correct?
Thank you!